# Distributed Application Command/Control and Monitoring

Tags: c++, monitoring

I'm working on a distributed system which has several nodes and I would like to be able to enable remote command and status monitoring on them. I've been looking around for a good solution and found [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/related-projects/dashboard/), but it seems overly complicated and cumbersome. Is there anything more lightweight that allows command/control and monitoring?

I need to be able to do the following things (at the very least):

1. Issue commands to the distributed nodes (start, stop, etc).
2. Show the status of the nodes within the system (up, down, throughput, errors, warnings, etc).
3. It would also be good if it has a C++ API.
4. A big plus would be if it has some sort of web interface.
5. It's affordable (even free)?

I can build one in-house, but if there is something already available then it would save me some time.

Comment: @sarnold, [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) seems very interesting, why don't you put that up as an answer...

Comment: Because I know nothing more about it than that. :)

Comment: @sarnold gotcha :), thanks for the tip tho!

Answer (score 0):

I have used PsExec and its quite helpful. Its a commandline tool, and I think it should meet most of the listed requirements.